# Getting rid of carriage return in xml via php

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to make an XML file from product database description and it works fine, except I get this  windows line brake symbol at the and of every line. They were using Microsoft Word to make a text first, then copy and paste into field form.

I tried numerous times escape it with php functions such as

```
str_replace(array('\r\n','\n','\r'),'',$text);
```

and nothing works.
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `str_replace(array('\r\n','\n','\r'),'',$text);` Or quick and simple: `str_replace(PHP_EOL,'',$text);`

Comment: [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) only takes  3 arguments, the 4th is optional but you wouldn't use it in this case.]

Comment: the symbol I'm getting is not allowed in this post. it is ampersant pound 13 semicolon

Comment: sorry about this I actually put them in array as well and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$text = str_replace(array("\r","\n","&#13;"),'',$text);
```

Comment: nope. still get this ampersant pound 13 semicolon symbol

Comment: Show a string with the problem in it... perhaps without the semicolumn. I don't deal with these type of characters every day.

Comment: It is &#13 plus semicolon

Comment: still the same output which is weird

Comment: You could make a sandboxed example like this: http://codepad.org/RtI6IY1E This way other people can understand your problem.